# how to prove this is monotonically decreasing without using $\sqrt{3}$ bound?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence:

$a_1 = 3$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{3}{2a_n}$

I've shown it's bounded below (can bound it by $\sqrt{3}$), or more easily by $1$.

I want to show it's monotonically decreasing.

$a_{n+1} \le a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I can do so by contradiction fairly easily, but it relies on the tight bound of $\sqrt{3}$. I'd like to use induction or a more direct method.

I run into this problem in my inductive step (if using induction):

$\frac{a_{n + 1}}{2} \le \frac{a_n}{2}$, but we have $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \ge \frac{1}{a_n}$, so that doesn't help us move forward.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with just proving that $a_n \ge \sqrt3$ for all $n$ and using that? I think you will *have* to prove this, because if $a_n$ were to ever dip below $\sqrt3$, it would stop being decreasing.

Comment: It is difficult to see that @MishaLavrov without first calculating the limit, so I'm trying to see if there's an alternate strategy, if I were to go step by step to the limit.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the limit to prove it. You don't even need to know what the limit is to (1) discover that $a_n \ge \sqrt3$ is the condition we need to conclude that $a_{n+1} \le a_n$, and (2) prove that $a_n \ge \sqrt3$ for all $n$ by induction.

Comment: Yes. That is actually exactly how I did it. I was therefore wondering if there was an alternate way @MishaLavrov

Comment: I doubt it, simply for the reason that it's so easy to go between the inequalities $a_n \ge \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{3}{2a_n}$ and $a_n \ge \sqrt3$. If you've shown one, you've basically shown the other.

Comment: Or you can use AM-GM to show that $ a_{n+1} = a_n / 2 + 3/(2a_n) \geq \sqrt{3}$ .